# Printing pdf files from firefox

Tags: firefox, printing, pdf

Got a brain teaser for everyone. :) I recently needed to turn in paperwork for insurance reasons. I found the pdf file for the form I needed online, however it would not let me print the file. When viewing the file in Firefox which is using the default viewer, I click the print button and click ok/print. The printer will just push out a blank page. If I save the file on my system and pull it up in any other pdf file viewer I can print the file without fail. Not sure what is happening. My printer is connected to my pc and the ubuntu is connected to a wireless network which shares the printer on the pc. The printer should be setup properly because I can print from any other application and any other file type. Not sure if this is normal or I am having a small issue. Have tried changing a few settings but no help. I have put everything back to the default settings the way it was. Anyone have any ideas? Not sure what else to do....

Comment: You should write your own answer in a separate answer instead of a comment and then accept your own answer. The answer you have accepted is not what worked for you as per your comment below.

Comment: It seems like [a bug inFirefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/997170)

Comment: Understood about the answer. My appologies, new to linux and the ask ubuntu website. Sincere thanks for the comment :) and the input on my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Visit Firefox official printing help.](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/fix-printing-problems-firefox)
2. Reinstall Firefox.

Comment: I went to the printing help and could not find anything that dealt with my issue. I removed and reinstalled firefox, no help. What I ended up doing was installing adobe reader add-on to firefox and used it as the default viewer. This has solved my issue. I wanted to set this up anyway, was curious if anyone else ran into this issue though. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact problem, but instead of installing the Adobe plug-in, I went into Firefox -> edit preferences -> Applications and changed the PDF action from "preview in Firefox" to "Use Document Viewer".  This launches a separate Evince window with the document which prints nicely.  I never liked the idea of pdf's being viewed in the browser window anyway, so I'm happy.  There is, however, something nasty wrong with Firefox for printing blank pages from it's preview window.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Happy to hear someone else had this issue. Wasnt sure if something was wrong with my setup or if this was a known problem. Starting to beleive its a problem with firefox/ubuntu. Thanks again for the input.